# Which is the best file system to use in an external hard drive?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What filesystem for shared (read/write) PC/Mac external drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/138319/what-filesystem-for-shared-read-write-pc-mac-external-drive)

I've bought a Samsung S2 500GB External Hard Drive. The disk came with FAT32 file system, but I formatted it to NTFS to use large files in it, but now I can't write the disk on Mac OS X. Which file system should I use that is compatible with large files and Mac OS X/Windows reading and writing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/235753/filesystem-to-use-for-external-hard-drive-to-be-used-with-mac-linux-and-windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), which becomes available for more and more OSes. OS X supports it since 10.6.5, Windows supports it since Vista. There are updates for oler Microsoft OSes.

exFAT supports large files.

Comment: Seems that exFAT is a good solution. It works with Windows 7 and Mac OS X for writing and reading large files.

Comment: I already tested it on a 16GB USB stick. It worked quite well. And there's a linux kernel module in the making (see sources in linked wikipedia article)

Answer (score 1):

This article, [How-to: Read and Write NTFS Windows Partition on Mac OS X](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifehack/how-to-read-and-write-ntfs-windows-partition-on-mac-os-x.html), should get you started.

Comment: NTFS-3g [no longer works](http://superuser.com/questions/253113/mac-os-x-read-write-ntfs-support) for the newest 64 bit only Macs.

Comment: This leads me to this: http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/. I really don't want to pay 25 EUR for NTFS support on Mac.

Comment: @FábioPerez There's still a free version if you scroll down a bit. Also, see the topic I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a perfect one; FAT32 has file size and filesystem size limitations on OSX, and NTFS isn't supported natively without add-ons like [NTFS-3g](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/) (which may not work reliably in 64-bit kernels).

Answer (score 0):

[Tuxera NTFS for MAC](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) Should be what your looking for to read and write to NTFS Partitions.

Comment: I don't want to pay 25 EUR just to write on NTFS.